# Why do I get extra system calls when compiling code directly to an executable vs. compiling to an object file and then manually linking?

Tags: c, gcc, system-calls, ld, strace

I want to compile this C code with the GNU C Compiler on Ubuntu without linking any standard libraries, having only the following code execute.

```
static void exit(long long code)
  {asm inline
  ("movq $60,%%rax\n"
  "movq %[code],%%rdi\n"
  "syscall"
  :
  :[code]"rm"(code)
  :"rax"
  ,"rdi");}
static void write(long long fd,char *msg,long long len)
  {asm inline
  ("movq $0x1,%%rax\n"
  "movq %[fd],%%rdi\n"
  "movq %[msg],%%rsi\n"
  "movq %[len],%%rdx\n"
  "syscall"
  :
  :[fd]"rm"(fd)
  ,[msg]"rm"(msg)
  ,[len]"rm"(len)
  :"rax"
  ,"rdi"
  ,"rsi"
  ,"rdx");}
#define PRINT(msg) write(1,msg,sizeof(msg))
void _start()
  {PRINT("Hello World.\n");
  exit(0);}
```

I compiled with `cc example.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -O3 -o example`.

When I called the output file I saw a lot of extra system calls with `strace` that should not have been there:

1. brk
2. arch_prctl
3. access
4. mmap
5. arch_prctl
6. mprotect

I then compiled like this: `cc example.c -c -O3 -o example.o; ld example.o -o example` and it did not do the extra syscalls. It even made the filesize somewhat smaller.

The `objdump -d` of it was exactly the same. In the `objdump -D` I found some extra symbols (_DYNAMIC,__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR,.interp) in the first case compared to the second, but still no sign of any extra syscalls in the code.

Do you know why I get the extra system calls with `cc example.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -O3 -o example` and not with `cc example.c -c -O3 -o example.o; ld example.o -o example`?

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way to invoke the syscalls.  It's possible to tell the compiler to put the values into specific registers for you, and to let it know which registers change and which ones don't.  This can both reduce the number of registers needed and the number of mov instructions required.  It can be particularly valuable if you are calling functions repeatedly.  Check out [this](https://godbolt.org/z/eE8fboWGn) for example.

Comment: I did not know about Register Constraints. Thank you for pointing it out! For anyone looking for them in the documentation, they are hidden in the Machine Constraints section -> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints . Just look up your architecture (probably x86 family for most people)

Comment: A couple other tidbits: Input Constraints (after the second colon) MUST have the same value when exiting the asm as on entry. asm statements with no output constraints are implicitly `volatile` (and thus cannot be optimized away).  When you add an output constraint (as I did), you will need to make it volatile if you never actually use the output value and the asm must always be executed.  And while inline asm is very cool to play with, I [wouldn't recommend it](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) for most production code.

Comment: Here is a short example code to illustrate the above points: http://ix.io/3RJC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what is happening.

If I compile the code with `cc example.c -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -O3 -o example` the compiler makes a dynamically linked executable. Dynamically linked executables have an `.interp` section. That is what I was seeing in my `objdump -D`.

Dynamically linked executables are executing via the program interpreter and the dynamic linker. The additional system calls I saw, came from the dynamic linker. I still do not know why the executable wants to dynamically link anything in a program that does not link any libraries and wants to be freestanding.

If you do not want the extra system calls from the dynamic linker - you should give gcc the extra `-static` option. The compiler does not automatically do this if there is no dynamic linking happening.